# Deploy AWS Glue Connection with Terraform does not work via Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, terraform, aws-glue

For a Glue Job I try to create a Glue Connection (Type: `NETWORK`) to a VPC to be able to connect to a RDS database from my code. It works when I deploy my Terraform script for the Glue Connection from Cloud9. However, when I use Azure DevOps it does not work (with a role with more permissions than used in Cloud9 (admin)). My question is how to fix it.

Terraform Glue Connection script:

```
resource "aws_glue_connection" "glue_invoice_vpc_connection" {
  name = "pite-pgov-${lower(var.exec_env)}-invoicevpcconnection"
  connection_type = "NETWORK"
  physical_connection_requirements {
    availability_zone      = "eu-central-1a"
    security_group_id_list = ["${var.securitygroup_id_1}"]
    subnet_id              = "${var.subnet_id_1}"
  }
}
```

DevOps runs for 50 min, keeping stuck on creating this `aws_glue_connection` following with this error:

```
2023-04-04T15:33:59.2027220Z [0m[1maws_glue_connection.glue_invoice_vpc_connection: Still creating... [51m10s elapsed][0m[0m
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7064840Z [31m╷[0m[0m
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7065291Z [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mcreating Glue Connection (pite-pgov-devt-invoicevpcconnection): InternalFailure: 
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7065759Z [31m│[0m [0m   status code: 500, request id: 02f45f0b-64be-41cc-aabe-3252ed4bf818[0m
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7065984Z [31m│[0m [0m
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7066271Z [31m│[0m [0m[0m  with aws_glue_connection.glue_invoice_vpc_connection,
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7066664Z [31m│[0m [0m  on gluejob_c1.tf line 1, in resource "aws_glue_connection" "glue_invoice_vpc_connection":
2023-04-04T15:34:02.7067036Z [31m│[0m [0m   1: resource "aws_glue_connection" "glue_invoice_vpc_connection" [4m{[0m[0m
```

Can anyone help finding out why this code does not work when deployed with Azure Devops pipeline?

I checked, the issue is not with the variables in my DevOps pipeline.

Comment: What are the permissions you have assigned to the role?

Comment: The role DevOps uses (AWS connection) has AdministratorAccess (Allow * Action on * Resource)

Comment: Uhm, ok, and do you have any kind of a network connection between Azure and AWS, e.g., VPN?